# How do I run a random thing whilst using an if statement?

Tags: python

```
if (response11 == 'slowly' or response11 == 'slow'):
  def dice_roll()
  DiceRoll = random.randint(1,2)
  return DiceRoll
  if (DiceRoll == 1):
    print('Bad luck, you were too slow\n\nand got eaten by the bugs!')
    time.sleep(4)
```

im unsure if this is close to how to do it however this is what i came up with. It errors at the def dice.roll() line. I am trying to get it so it randomizes the chances of moving slow either working or not working. eg; it roles the dice and if it lands on 1 then you die however if it lands on 2 you survive.

Comment: please format your question properly.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, like your local code, for now it's wrong

Comment: could you please provide a complete, minimal and reproducible code sample, including all `import` statements?
please consider this help article for guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "It errors at the def dice.roll() line" And, what is the error?

Comment: That function declaration is missing a `:`, but im not sure why you have that line within that if statement at all anyway

Comment: There are numerous problems in your code, and it seems that many basic concepts are unclear for you (you have a class definition in an unexpected place, a `return` in the middle, you're using the name of the function like a variable name, your indentation is broken... I would strongly recommend that you review your learning material and/or some Python tutorial, that would be of great help for you. SO is not a tutorial site, so this is not really the right place to address all of this.

Comment: Take it slow, start with a good Python tutorial, and master the basics. You'll never get anywhere by mashing together random code snippets you find online if you don't have a firm understanding of the way the language works. The code you've posted is meaningless for multiple reasons, as already pointed out. You have to walk before you can run.